# How to create a unique ID field in MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, suitecrm

How to automatically create unique ID field in MySQL (SuiteCRM)? For example: 'e3df34-dg324g-sdsew23-dsdsw2'

python:

```
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, ('sdi_234023', 'Alex'))

        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Comment: *For example: 'e3df34-dg324g-sdsew23-dsdsw2'* Non-standard value... Generate it via your own user-defined function.

Comment: What should the id look like? Is it a fixed format or a random one?

Answer (score 2):

You can you generate random uuid for the same. Using following code.

```
    from uuid import uuid4
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (str(uuid4), 'Alex'))

        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()
```